# AngularJS - Controller inside iframe template dose not initialized

Tags: javascript, angularjs, iframe

I have an iframe inside my angular partial which loads on $route

ex: /dashboard/a-view-with-iframe

```
<iframe id="portal" src="/templates/view.html" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Now the view.html has the below code

```
<div ng-controller="portalViewCtrl">
    checking...
    <span ng-bind-html="view"></span>
</div>
```

The controller is defined as follows

```
app.controller('portalViewCtrl', function ($scope) {
    console.log('not happening');
});
```

When my main partial is loaded the iframe loads as well and from within the view i am able to see "checking..." as well, but the console.log() form within the defined controller does not fire. I am not sure if this is possible or i am missing out something very silly here.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: getting any error ?

Comment: You can't share scope with the iframe (out of the box). You have to create new app inside (ex. by adding ng-app)

Comment: @AmeyaDeshpande Nope,

Comment: @lujcon you mean inside the view or with the iframe

Comment: ex: https://github.com/james2doyle/angular-through-iframe

Comment: in general - don't use iframe - your app will not work inside iframe. I can see that you are in control of the view.html so just replace iframe with div ;)
If you have to use iframe - you have to create separate app inside it so your view.html has to contain necessary scripts, app definition, app bootstrapping (ng-app) etc.

Comment: Exactly, The reason i was using an iframe is because i am bringing some scrapped data from another website inside mine. When i use a div for this all the css from the scrapped data overrides my css, hence using the iframe. But since the complexity is too high here i guess will have to find another way to do it

Comment: Changes in the scrapped data is the least complex solution i have found, Doing it inside the iframe with the above method is very complex